# Android Kotlin RxJava Retrofit - empty DisposableObserver LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java, android-livedata

I'm implementing an Android application in Kotlin that uses an API as it's primary source for data. I use Kotlin, RXjava, Retrofit and Dagger to make it work.

But for some reason my person object at the onNext function is empty. Even though I see the http method call data in the Logcat, and it has the correct person object.

I'm requesting a person object from JSON:

```
{
  "persons": [{
      "personId": 1,
      "personName": "Bert",
      "personAge": 19,
      "isFemale": "false",
      "birthDate": "2000-06-28T00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

ApiInterface:

```
@GET("persons")
fun getPerson(@Query("personId") personId: Int): Observable<Person>
```

PersonRepository:

```
class PersonRepository @Inject constructor(val apiInterface: ApiInterface) {
  fun getPerson(personId: Int): Observable<Person>{
    return apiInterface.getPerson(personId)
  }
}
```

Person ViewModel:

```
class PersonViewModel @Inject constructor(private val personRepositoy: PersonRepository) : ViewModel() {
  var personResult: MutableLiveData<Person> = MutableLiveData()
  var personError: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
  lateinit var disposableObserver: DisposableObserver<Person>

  fun personResult(): LiveData<Person> {
    return personResult
  }
  fun personError(): LiveData<String> {
    return personError
  }

  fun loadPerson(personId: Int) {
    disposableObserver: object : DisposableObserver<Person>() {
    override fun onComplete() {}

    override fun onNext(person: Person){ //this is empty for some reason
      personResult.postValue(person)
    }

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
      personError.postValue(e.message)
    }
  }

  personRepository.getPerson(personId)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(disposableObserver)
  }

fun disposeElements() {
     if(null !- disposableObserver && !disposableObserver.isDisposed) { 
       disposableObserver.dispose() 
     }
}
}
```

PersonActivity where the call is made:

```
@Inject
lateinit var personViewModelFactory: PersonViewModelFactory
lateinit var personViewModel: PersonViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_person)
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)

 personViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, personViewModelFactory).get(PersonViewModel::class.java)

 personViewModel.loadPerson(1)
 personViewModel.personResult().observe(this, Observer<Person> {
  //some code that uses it
 }
}
```

The getPerson call returns the correct person which I can see in the logs, but it doesn't post the value in personResult, like I want. I don't know why.

Edit: Added the Person class as requested. Note that @Json is the Moshi equivalent of @SerializedName from GSON.

```
data class Person (
  @Json(name = "personId")
  val personId: Int,

  @Json(name = "personName")
  val name: String,

  @Json(name = "personAge")
  val age: Int,

  @Json(name = "isFemale")
  val isFemale: Boolean,

  @Json(name = "birthDate")
  val birthDate: GregorianCalendar

)
```

Comment: I think it is because you haven't called the method where you are initializing your disposableObserver.

Comment: @p.mathew13 No I do call then inside an Activity, but I didn't think adding it would be relevant to the question, same for Dagger, but I'll add it.

Comment: @Walt, the JSON response looks like it returns a list of person objects. Does your `Person` definition really account for this?

Comment: @SanlokLee the personId is unique so I should only get one person object. Are you suggesting that I receive a list with 1 object instead?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to point out that your JSON response has "persons: a list of persons" form. Your response returns a list of `Person` with 1 object in the list, while your response expects a `Person` object itself, so there is a type mismatch. Unless, of course, your `Person` definition looks like `Person(val persons: List<ActualPerson>)`. Can you show your `Person` class just to be sure?

Comment: @SanlokLee I added the Person class .I understand what you mean, that's why when I request a list of Person objects, it works. But when I request one single Person object, via an ID, I expect a single object of the type Person, and not a list of the Person type with one single object inside. When I request a Person object via an unique ID, it's always going to be a single object. So the solution would be to change everything to lists even though I know there's only going to be one object?

Comment: @Walt, yes that is correct. I have added some example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid mismatch between the JSON response and the actual object to be used, define a intermediate class something like this:

```
data class PersonResponse(
      @Json(name = "persons")
      val persons: List<Person>
)
```

Example api class:

```
@GET("persons")
fun getPerson(@Query("personId") personId: Int): Observable<PersonResponse>    

@GET("persons")
fun getAllPersons(): Observable<PersonResponse>
```

Example repository class:

```
fun getPerson(personId: Int): Observable<Person>{
    // Convert PersonResponse -> Person
    return apiInterface.getPerson(personId)
        .doOnNext { value -> Log.d(SOME_LOG_TAG, "onNext: value=$value") }
        .doOnError { error -> Log.d(SOME_LOG_TAG, "onNext: value=${e.getMessage()}") }
        .flatMap { response ->
            // Check if the list contains exactly one Person and throw error if it doesn't
            if (response.persons.size == 1) 
                Observable.just(response.persons[0])
            else
                Observable.error(Throwable("Something's wrong"))
        }
}


fun getAllPerson(): Observable<List<Person>> {
    // Convert PersonResponse -> List<Person>
    return apiInterface.getAllPersons()
        .map { response -> response.persons }
}
```

As you can see repository code can look quite messy. I suggest making an intermediate layer between your api class and repository class which does all the conversions.

Comment: @Walt, thank you for spotting it. you can just remove "return" in `flatMap()`

Comment: unfortunately personResult.postValue(person) is still empty, even though I can see the call in the logcat being successful, and I don't see any errors. Could it be that it does not know how to convert the ISO 8601 date format to gregoriancalendar? Althoug I've written a converter for it but maybe it's not fully working thus doens't initialize the data? But not sure if this would make sense since a list of ```Persons``` does work

Comment: Can you log inside the `flatMap()` and see if `response` is null or `response.persons.size` is 1?

Comment: How should I log it, I can't see it in the debugger.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by you can't see in the debugger. Does it means that nothing is logged? I updated the answer with an example code but simply putting `Log.d(...)` inside the `flatMap()` should also work.

Comment: Okay so if I don't add the flatmap stuff, but directly send the List of objects to my ViewModel, and then just use ```person = it[0]``` it works, so I guess it's the flatmap logic thats faulty? I do want to be able to send just one object like in your example though

Comment: Above `flatMap()` logic seems fine. It looks like your 'it' is not exactly like `PersonResponse` above. If you don't like the `flatMap()` logic then you can replace that `flatMap` block with map block and parse it there. For example, `.map { it.persons[0] }` or `.map { it[0] }` depends on your implementation.

Comment: Alright, I fixed it by just adding ```Observable<List<Person>>``` at the apiInterface, so your solution is correct, but for some reason it doesn't work with the ```PersonResponse``` class, so I think the name persons is not found, because when I receive the call inside the logcat, I don't see the tag "persons", just the person object inside curly brackets and around that square ones. That's why I was thinking I'm only receiving one object instead of a list in the first place.